# Cmd console on first boot of Win server after installation.

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012

I' just installed  windows server 2012 but on the first boot, after password changing menu, windows stop and shows me a black display with cmd console 
What should I tap type to run desktop?

Comment: It sounds like you chose a [Server Core Installation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831786.aspx). Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You installed Server Core.

At the command prompt, type `powershell`

Then type `Install-WindowsFeature Server-Gui-Mgmt-Infra,Server-Gui-Shell –Restart`

Comment: Thanks. to invoke the installer from DVD?

Comment: The command that I gave will use Windows Updates over the internet. If you need to specify alternate install media, add `–Source c:\mountdir\windows\winsxs` to the command.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried downloading **Windows Server 2016** and **Windows Server 2019**, both `.ISO` and `.VHDX` versions, the command `Install-WindowsFeature Server-Gui-Mgmt-Infra,Server-Gui-Shell –Restart` doesn't work any more.

The file `install.wim` is there in the `D:\` drive

[image]

I even tried to mount it on `C:\mount` but no joy, the command `Install-WindowsFeature Server-Gui-Mgmt-Infra, Server-Gui-Shell -Source C:\mount\windows\winsxs` won't install the feature.

The only way was to reinstall from scratch and install the right version:

[image]

Pretty annoying.